# How to find the last record of an associated table in cakephp?

Tags: php, cakephp, model, cakephp-2.0

I am using cakephp 2.4.5. I want to find the last record of an associated table. Below is my code

```
    $Latest = $this->ParentModel->find('first',array(
                           'conditions' => array('ParentModel.id'=>$id),
                           'order' => array('ParentModel.AssociatedModel.id' => 'DESC')
                                                          ));
```

This code has missing column error with `ParentModel.AssociatedModel.id` but the id column is definitely there. Does it look right in the first place? If not, how can I fix this part or is there a better implementation? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Have you tried to read the manual about retrieving data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html)? It is clearly explained there.

**If** AssociatedModel is somehow associated [with one of the four association types](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html) with ParentModel, you'll have to use this syntax:

```
$Latest = $this->ParentModel->find('first',array(
   'contain' => array('AssociatedModel'),
   'conditions' => array('ParentModel.id' => $id),
   'order' => array('AssociatedModel.id' => 'DESC')
));
```

Make sure the other model is included by using recursive or contain(). [See this page about Containable](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html).

**If** your field name in the DB is really containing a dot CakePHP2 will have a problem with that because it uses the dot notation as separator. At least I've never used a dot in a database field, it's doable but doesn't make much sense and obviously breaks Cake, no idea if you can work around that.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do "cross conditions" though associated models, but you can use `Containable` behavior to filter associated models.

For this, you have to bind the behavior to your model through:

```
public $uses = array('Containable');
```

And then do your query:

```
$this->ParentModel->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('ParentModel.id' => $id),
    'contain' => array(
        'AssociatedModel' => array(
            'limit' => 1,
            'order' => array('id DESC')
        )
    )
));
```

This will give you the parent model, and the last associated model.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it should be like this

```
    $Latest = $this->ParentModel->AssociatedModel->find('first',array(
                       'conditions' => array('ParentModel.id'=>$id),
                       'order' => array('AssociatedModel.id DESC')
                                                      ));
```

Check if it is correct.